# Using loop to less the uses of if formula

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

Good Day!

I am writing a code in which I have 03 cell in which user will input yes or no. After submitting the answer the user will get a result in another cell. Like if his answer is yes-yes-yes then the result will be 400-400-400 and if his answer is yes-no-yes then the result will be 400-0-400 and if his answer is yes-no-no then the result will be 400-0-0 and like this so on.

I have written a code

```
If Cells(Number, 8).Value = "yes" And Cells(Number, 9).Value = "yes" And Cells(Number, 10).Value = "no" Then
        Range(planningRange).Value = Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0) & "-" & Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0) & "-" & "0"
    ElseIf Cells(Number, 8).Value = "yes" And Cells(Number, 10).Value = "no" And Cells(Number, 9).Value = "yes" Then
        Range(planningRange).Value = Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0) & "-" & "0" & "-" & Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0)
    ElseIf Cells(Number, 9).Value = "no" And Cells(Number, 10).Value = "yes" And Cells(Number, 8).Value = "yes" Then
        Range(planningRange).Value = "0" & "-" & Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0) & "-" & Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0)
    ElseIf Cells(Number, 8).Value = "yes" And Cells(Number, 9).Value = "yes" And Cells(Number, 10).Value = "yes" Then
        Range(planningRange).Value = Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0) & "-" & Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0) & "-" & Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0)
    Else
        Range(planningRange).Value = "-"
    End If
```

The good news is the code work perfectly!
But the bad news is this is not the proper way of it. Because this is well if the input cell is 03 or 04. But if my input cell is going to be 11. So, if I want this probably I will have to write around 243 `if` formula. But that is not possible. So, can anyone suggest any kind of loop or anything else which can make this easy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the output as a string, then build the string up part-by-part; you want one `if` statement per part, not one for each possible combination. Also that way you can loop through all 11 input cells one by one.

```
Dim strOutput as String
Dim i as long
For i = 8 to 18
    If Cells(Number, i).Value = "yes" Then
        strOutput = strOutput & Round(Cells(Number, 18), 0) & "-"
    ElseIf Cells(Number, i).Value = "no" Then
        strOutput = strOutput & "0-"
    Else
        'not sure what you'd want to happen if neither condition is matched?
        strOutput = strOutput & "  "
    End if
Next

'That will leave a dash on the end of strOutput so better remove it
strOutput = Left(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1)

'Finally put strOutput into the desired cell
Range(PlanningRange).Value = strOutput
```

Comment: Done @spencer Barnes ! It worked. You really get rid of my stress. You understood my problem that really helped a lot. Keep it up bro :)